# Cloning an existing shopify site to a new site

Tags: clone, shopify

I want to be able to clone an instance of an existing shopify site into a new shopify site. (This is in order for me to create a test / staging environment) Are there are any tools or scripts out there which could help me achieve this? The clone should include items such as customers and products etc. The only method I could find was in the official documentation and seems to be a manual export / import type [operation](https://docs.shopify.com/support/other/general-information/how-do-i-duplicate-my-store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your full theme into a zip file. Customers, products and orders can be exported too and imported to the new Shopify site.
Settings: domains, payment gateways and other minor parts, you'll need to add them manually.

Comment: thank you @alexandresaiz; seems you can't import orders in trivially (need to use the API) as at [the present time](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/migrating-to-shopify-importing-past-orders-104013);  (_noting that the link is from 2014 however couldn't find any other references either_)